# Angular2: How to navigate to an new url with changing some route parameters?

Tags: angular, parameters, router

I have some routing code like this:

```
// routing.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':group',
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'prod', loadChildren: './prod/prod.module#ProdModule' },
      { path: 'test', loadChildren: './test/test.module#TestModule', },
    ]
  }
];
```

The effect I expected is some navigation like this:
**localhost:4200/a/x**  => **localhost:4200/b/x**
The 'x' can be 'prod' or 'test'.
I want to change only the parameter **group** and remain other routes unchanged.

In my MainComponent, I write some code and have no idea about how to do the navigation:

```
// MainComponent
this.activatedRoute.paramMap
  .subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
    let originalGroup = params.get('group');
    if (originalGroup === 'a') {
      // this.router.navigate();  // <= How to change the group with other routes remaining unchanged ???
    }
  });
```

Comment: did't understand? can you please explain?

Comment: You can either use the `ActivatedRoute` instance to get the current URI, manipulate and use in your `router.navigate`; You can perform a relative navigation to the current route; You can access the parent router and manipulate it to your needs.

It's all just a matter of how you want to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a hack, but you can edit it to make it more generic.

```
// MainComponent
this.activatedRoute.paramMap
  .subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
    let originalGroup = params.get('group');
    if (originalGroup === 'a') {
       // if you are in prod code. (change the prod to test if you are in test code)
       this.router.navigate(['/b','prod']);  

    }
  });
```